# React Bootstrap and deep linking tabs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to link to a tab on a page and I'm a little lost on how to go about doing this. It doesn't seem to be documented anywhere and I can't seem to get it to work off of my own back. I've tried converting from the lower level tabs api to nav.items component and inserting a href instead of eventKey as advised from an issue post on github.

```
<Tab.Container id="left-tabs-example" defaultActiveKey="#first">
    <Row>
        <Col sm={3}>
            <Nav variant="pills" className="flex-column">
                <Nav.Item>
                    <Nav.Link href="#first">Tab 1</Nav.Link>
                </Nav.Item>
                <Nav.Item>
                    <Nav.Link href="#second">Tab 2</Nav.Link>
                </Nav.Item>
            </Nav>
        </Col>
        <Col sm={9}>
            <Tab.Content>
                <Tab.Pane eventKey="#first">
                    <p>first</p>
                </Tab.Pane>
                <Tab.Pane eventKey="#second">
                    <p>second</p>
                </Tab.Pane>
            </Tab.Content>
        </Col>
    </Row>
</Tab.Container>
```

However when I visit `/mypage#second` it doesn't open the page on that tab.

Any guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure it out.

I setup my route to capture params ie: `mypage/:params` and then captured it in my component passing in the params as props ie:

```
const Applications = ({match}) => {
 ...
}
```

I then set up my tabs as follows:

```
<Tabs id="controlled-tab-example" activeKey={key} onSelect={k => setKey(k)}>
    <Tab eventKey="all" title="All">
        <p>First</p>
    </Tab>
    <Tab eventKey="first" title="First">
        <p>Second</p>
    </Tab>
    <Tab eventKey="second" title="Second">
        <p>Third</p>
    </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

With the initial state

```
const [key, setKey] = useState('all');
```

Then on useEffect I capture the params and set it to the state.

```
useEffect(() => {
        setKey(match.params.id);
    }, []);
```

Comment: Great idea actually!!!